# Firebase AppCheck >=30% unverified request both iOS and Android

Tags: swift, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I am integrated `Firebase` `AppCheck` to `Android` and `iOS` for >1 month ago and monitoring the status to decide the enforcement.

I am focusing on `Authentication` one. The issue is currently still >= `30%` request is unverified.

I followed exactly this docs to integrate without custom AppCheck provider

- Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider
- iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider

**NOTE:**

- I tried to enforcement and logged error message to debug and see exactly around 30%
  user got error as below.
- This issue happened on both Android and iOS.
- I also logged app version and saw user already updated to latest app version with AppCheck already integrated.

> ae.g: An internal error has occurred. [ Firebase App Check token is
> invalid. ] at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth

##### Current AppCheck monitoring status

[image]

##### Android Integrity quota does not have any issue.

[image]

Does anyone got the same issue?

Comment: Hey! I have the same issue; were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, I have no idea. Firebase Support tell me should turn off App Check but with current status, I could not turn it on.

Comment: is your app published in the App Store / Play Store? is this related to these 2 posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77116288/why-is-appcheck-randomly-generating-invalid-requests-from-published-android-but  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77166098/how-to-check-the-reason-why-app-check-does-not-verify-the-integrity-of-an-app-in

Comment: Yes, my app already in Play Store and App Store. Now status is 3% unverified.

Comment: what is you appcheck playintegrity version ?

Comment: I am using firebase-bom:32.7.3

Comment: im using the same and facing the same issue , do your google-service.json contains "firebase_url" ?

Comment: No, not contains "firebase_url".